# What is the best way to serve AC power to a 12v - 5v DC regulator with 1Amp current?

Tags: power-supply, transformer

What transformer should I use to supply AC voltage in a circuit which is using 7812 and 7805 - Positive Voltage Regulators. I need approximately 1Amp current. What is the best way to minimize the physical volume of the supply? I shall be using an Arduino board from the 5v supply. Most importantly I need low physical volume of the transformer or related circuit to supply the AC voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the specifications you've presented, you need a transformer with dual secondaries: one at 14 to 16 volts center-tapped for the 5 volt supply, and one with about 24 volts center-tapped for the 12 volt supply. You have not specified the 12 volt current you need.

You cannot use a single secondary winding for both voltages. The rectified and filtered raw DC for the 12 volts must be a minimum of about 15 volts, to allow 3 volts across the 7812. This same 15 volts, when applied to the 7805, will dissipate 10 watts in the 7805 when supplying 1 amp, and I don't think you know how to build a proper heat sink to handle this.

To find a transformer, go to the web sites of suppliers such as Allied Electronics, Digikey or Newark, and use their search functions. Specifically, look at Power Transformers, and make sure you have specified both the correct input voltage range and frequency. You appear to be in India, so you need 230V @ 50 Hz.

As for transformer size, you take what you get. Transformer manufacturers are very tightly constrained by the magnetic properties of the core materials available, and if they could produce a smaller transformer for a given level of performance they would. After all, smaller is cheaper, so they could sell for less than their competitors and thereby sell more units, making a greater profit.

I very strongly suspect that you don't want to do this at all. What will give you better results, and cost less in the long run, is to buy a switching power supply with both 5 volt and 12 volt outputs. Not only will it be cheaper, it will be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You will need: 1) Transformer 2) Bridge Rectifier 3) Large-ish value smoothing capacitor. That's all you need.  Best advice I can give you is search on line for "full wave bridge rectification circuit", find one that will deliver 1 amp at around 14 volts in order to drive the 7812. Learn about how the full wave bridge rectification circuit works (it's quite easy), and then you can select the right value of transformer voltage and smoothing capacitor value.
The size of the capacitor affects how much ripple there will be on the output of the power supply, the bigger the cap, the lower the output voltage ripple (which is at 100Hz).  But as you're using a voltage regulator, the regulator can tolerate a fair amount of ripple, it can tolerate quite a large variation of input voltage, so you can get away with a smaller value of smoothing capacitor.

The 7812 and 7805 regulators are very popular and there are lots of circuits out there using them.

The size of the whole thing is going to be determined by the size of the transformer, so don't over specify it. You may find a toridal type (donut shaped) might be a bit smaller.

You should be ok with a 1 or 2 Amp transformer, (if you're wanting 1 Amp from both the 7812 and 7815 then you should opt for a 2 Amp transformer.)

Transformer voltage: remember a transformer outputs 50Hz (or 60Hz if you are in the USA) AC. A transformer that has a voltage of 12V rms actually has a peak voltage of 12/0.707 = 16.9 Volts. After feeding into the bridge rectifier and smoothing capacitor you should get 16.9V DC output, now the voltage will drop when current starts to draw, but that should be high enough to drive the 7812. On the 7812, whilst it's output voltage is 12V, the input needs to be 2 or more volts higher, so you need a minimum supply voltage to the 7812 of 14V.

So you should be ok with a 12V rms transformer at 1 or 2 amps.